# Possibility of simulating quantum physics and relativity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, simulations, relativity, computational-physics

I must be clear; this is not a 'specific' question, but rather a hypothetical one.

As of now, computer physics simulations are becoming more and more advanced, and I am programming one now. I was interested in the feasibility that perhaps one could emulate quantum physics or relativity in a physics simulation. Obviously, there are many problems at first, but I think that it would be very interesting to attempt such a simulation to observe the systems in a controlled environment.

Comment: This seems to be a list-based question, which would make it off-topic here.

Comment: Note also that relativistic hydrodynamics is done regularly in astrophysics.

Comment: @KyleKanos "a list-based question" what does that mean?

Comment: @KyleKanos Ok i'll remove it, but for future reference, what do you mean by list-based? Thanks.

Comment: List based means that the answer is basically going to be a list of items. In this case, it'd appear that an answer would be a list of simulations involving QM or SR/GR. I could be wrong in my reading of the question, so please don't delete it (closure requires 5 votes, so 4 people to agree with me).

Comment: @KyleKanos Ok that makes sense. perhaps I worded the question wrong, but I was going towards a discussion of how QM could be simulated - or if it could realistically.

Comment: Well you include relativity in your title and body, so if your interests are in how *QM* can be modeled, you should remove the references to relativity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was meant to be a comment but ended up being too long.

In a sense, both special relativity and quantum physics are incorporated in simulations already. One example would be be [Monte Carlo event generators](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2599) used for simulating collider physics. MC generators use random numbers to simulate probabilistic quantum mechanical effects which represent probabilities of interactions occurring. MC generators also incorporate relativity, because the initial and final state particles are usually relativistic.

But relativity is much easier to simulate than quantum mechanics. The covariant formulation of SR makes it so. Take a look at this game-like simulation, called a [Slower Speed of Light](http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/)

It is currently believed that to simulate full QM effects (effects like entanglement, tunneling etc.) we would need a [universal quantum simulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantum_simulator) which is essentially a fully operational quantum computer which *itself* works on quantum mechanical laws, thus avoiding huge (exponential actually) simulation times. [This](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~christos/classics/Feynman.pdf) is a paper by Richard Feynman which discusses the matter further, called *"Simulating Physics with Computers"*.

I do not know of any current developments on the subject, so any corrections will be happily considered.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot and hopefully i'll be able to gain some ground on simulating some complex things. Wasn't aware of that article by Feynman - thanks!